# Using Contour Detection to extract required data from image

Tags: python, opencv

I have been trying to extract text from a document by utilizing the coordinates obtained from boundingRect function. While these coordinates work when trying to draw the contours i cant seem to extract the individual characters onto a temporary image file.
This is the code i used

```
[x,y,w,h] = cv2.boundingRect(contour)
roi = image[y:y+h,x:x+w]
m[y:y+h, x:x+w]=roi
```

and i've also tried

```
cv2.drawContours(m,[c],-1,0,1)
image = cv2.bitwise_and(image,image, mask=m)
```

Comment: i dont see any reason for it to not work...Do you mean writing the image using `cv2.imwrite(filename,roi)` by  **" i cant seem to extract the individual characters onto a temporary image file"**
 Please post the full code

Comment: Share the image

Comment: issue was resolved. used a alternate solution which involved performing operations on the original image.